# How can i use RowFilter.dateFilter on LocalDate columns

Tags: java, swing, tablerowsorter

This is the date : `String date = "01.11.2020";`

*Column1* : `SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyy");`

*Column2* : `DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");`

*Column1* parsed with `SimpleDateFormat` and *Column2* parsed with `DateTimeFormatter`.

```
//Column1      Column2
01 Kas 2020   2020-11-01
```

I have a *JComboBox* with items like this `{"ALL", "LAST 1 WEEK", "LAST 1 MONTH", "LAST 1 YEAR"}`
So when i want to see `LAST 1 WEEK` dates i use a code like this.

```
TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(m1);
java.util.List<RowFilter<Object,Object>> filters = new ArrayList<RowFilter<Object,Object>>(2);
table.setRowSorter(sorter);

filters.add(RowFilter.dateFilter(ComparisonType.AFTER, date,columnIndex));
RowFilter<Object,Object> serviceFilter = RowFilter.andFilter(filters);
sorter.setRowFilter(serviceFilter);
```

It works fine with *Column1*. But it does not sort *Column2*. I guess it does not accept it as a date.

*Column1* is `Date.Class`* column in table model. *Column2* is `LocalDate.Class` in table model.*( I have tryed to make both `Date.Class` but Column2 gives error. )*.

Is there any way i can use `RowFilter.dateFilter` on `LocalDate.Class` columns.

I wrote some codes to explain it with more details. Here is a class for example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.RowFilter;
import javax.swing.RowFilter.ComparisonType;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;

public class frm1 extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTable table;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    frm1 frame = new frm1();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     * @throws ParseException 
     */
    public frm1() throws ParseException {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 501, 425);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        
        DefaultTableModel m1 = new DefaultTableModel() {
            public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
                switch (column) {
                    case 0:
                        return Date.class;
                    case 1:
                        return LocalDate.class;
                    default:
                        return String.class;
                }
            }
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                return false;
             }
        };
        
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(10, 11, 263, 325);
        contentPane.add(scrollPane);
        
        table = new JTable();
        table.setBounds(329, 256, 1, 1);
        //contentPane.add(table);
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
        
        JComboBox cbx_date = new JComboBox();
        cbx_date.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"ALL", "LAST 1 WEEK", "LAST 1 MONTH", "LAST 1 YEAR"}));
        cbx_date.setBounds(283, 53, 163, 31);
        contentPane.add(cbx_date);
        
        JComboBox cbx_localdate = new JComboBox();
        cbx_localdate.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"ALL", "LAST 1 WEEK", "LAST 1 MONTH", "LAST 1 YEAR"}));
        cbx_localdate.setBounds(283, 125, 163, 31);
        contentPane.add(cbx_localdate);
        
        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("With Date");
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(283, 11, 163, 31);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);
        
        JLabel lblWithLocaldate = new JLabel("With LocalDate");
        lblWithLocaldate.setBounds(283, 95, 163, 31);
        contentPane.add(lblWithLocaldate);
        
        //Columns
        table.setModel(m1);
        Object[] columns = {"Date","Local Date"};
        m1.setColumnIdentifiers(columns);
        
        TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(m1);
        java.util.List<RowFilter<Object,Object>> filters = new ArrayList<RowFilter<Object,Object>>(2);
        table.setRowSorter(sorter);
        
        //Rows
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyy");
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");
        String[] dates = {"01.08.2020","05.08.2020","20.08.2020","21.08.2020","01.09.2020","15.09.2020","01.10.2020","15.10.2020","01.11.2020","01.08.2019","01.07.2019"};
        Object[] rows = new Object[2];
        for(int i=0;i<dates.length;i++) {
            rows[0]=sdf.parse(dates[i]);
            rows[1]=LocalDate.parse(dates[i],formatter);
            m1.addRow(rows);
        }
        //Date state change event.
        cbx_date.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                filters.clear();
                String selected = cbx_date.getSelectedItem().toString();
                if(!selected.equals("ALL")) {
                    filters.add(RowFilter.dateFilter(ComparisonType.AFTER, datereturn(selected),0));
                    filters.add(RowFilter.dateFilter(ComparisonType.BEFORE,new Date(),0));
                }
                RowFilter<Object,Object> serviceFilter = RowFilter.andFilter(filters);
                sorter.setRowFilter(serviceFilter);
            }
        });
        //LocalDate state change event.
        cbx_localdate.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                filters.clear();
                String selected = cbx_localdate.getSelectedItem().toString();
                if(!selected.equals("ALL")) {
                    filters.add(RowFilter.dateFilter(ComparisonType.AFTER, datereturn(selected),1));
                    filters.add(RowFilter.dateFilter(ComparisonType.BEFORE,new Date(),1));
                }
                RowFilter<Object,Object> serviceFilter = RowFilter.andFilter(filters);
                sorter.setRowFilter(serviceFilter);
            }
        });
    }
    //Returs the date as wanted.
    public static Date datereturn (String selected) {
        if(selected.equals("LAST 1 WEEK")) {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -7);
            cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);// make 1 less date so i can get the EQUALS day.Becouse of ComparisonType.AFTER
            Date old = cal.getTime();
            return old;
        }else if(selected.equals("LAST 1 MONTH")) {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.add(Calendar.MONTH , -1);
            cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
            Date old = cal.getTime();
            return old;
        }else if(selected.equals("LAST 1 YEAR")) {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.add(Calendar.YEAR , -1);
            cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
            Date old = cal.getTime();
            return old;
        }else {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            Date old = cal.getTime();
            return old;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your ItemListener for the LocalDate state change event, your RowFilter is using a Date.  You're comparing a Date to a LocalDate.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Yes sir that is the problem but how can i filter LocalDates with a Date. I cant find the way. Or just we can't use dateFilter with LocalDates.

Comment: You would have to write your own RowFilter class and create a static method to take in a LocalDate.  That task would be difficult.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc i understand thanks for the tip sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out how to write a `RowFilter` for a LocalDate.

When you create a GUI, you should use [Swing layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).  I used the `FlowLayout`, `BorderLayout`, and `GridBagLayout` to create the GUI.  Absolute positioning is brittle and does not work well when you move from one computer to another with a different monitor or different operating system.

Also, it helps a lot to separate your code into methods and classes.  The smaller the method or class, the easier it is to test.  Believe me, I ran hundreds of tests before I got the RowFilter to work correctly.

Here's the GUI I created.

[image: Date Picker Example GUI]

Please review all of the code.  The code with the custom `RowFilter` is in the `LocalDateItemListener` class.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.RowFilter;
import javax.swing.RowFilter.ComparisonType;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

public class DatePickerExample implements Runnable {

    private DefaultTableModel model;

    private JFrame frame;

    private JTable table;

    private TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new DatePickerExample());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        frame = new JFrame("Date Picker Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(createTablePanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(createControlPanel(), BorderLayout.AFTER_LINE_ENDS);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createControlPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        JPanel innerPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        innerPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(
                5, 5, 5, 5));

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("With Date");
        innerPanel.add(lblNewLabel, gbc);

        String[] options = { "ALL", "LAST 1 WEEK", "LAST 1 MONTH",
                "LAST 1 YEAR" };

        gbc.gridy++;
        JComboBox<String> cbx_date = new JComboBox<>();
        cbx_date.setModel(
                new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>(options));
        cbx_date.addItemListener(new DateItemListener(sorter));
        innerPanel.add(cbx_date, gbc);

        gbc.gridy++;
        JLabel lblWithLocaldate = new JLabel("With LocalDate");
        innerPanel.add(lblWithLocaldate, gbc);

        gbc.gridy++;
        JComboBox<String> cbx_localdate = new JComboBox<>();
        cbx_localdate.setModel(
                new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>(options));
        cbx_localdate.addItemListener(new LocalDateItemListener(sorter));
        innerPanel.add(cbx_localdate, gbc);

        panel.add(innerPanel);
        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel createTablePanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        model = new MyTableModel();

        // Columns
        Object[] columns = { "Date", "Local Date" };
        model.setColumnIdentifiers(columns);

        // Rows
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyy");
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
                "dd.MM.yyyy");
        String[] dates = { "01.08.2020", "05.08.2020", "20.08.2020",
                "21.08.2020", "01.09.2020", "15.09.2020",
                "01.10.2020", "15.10.2020", "01.11.2020",
                "01.08.2019", "01.07.2019" };
        Object[] rows = new Object[2];
        for (int i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
            try {
                rows[0] = sdf.parse(dates[i]);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            rows[1] = LocalDate.parse(dates[i], formatter);
            model.addRow(rows);
        }

        table = new JTable(model);
        sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(model);
        table.setRowSorter(sorter);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        panel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        return panel;
    }

    public class MyTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
            switch (column) {
            case 0:
                return Date.class;
            case 1:
                return LocalDate.class;
            default:
                return String.class;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
            return false;
        }

    }

    public class DateItemListener implements ItemListener {

        private List<RowFilter<Object, Object>> filters =
                new ArrayList<RowFilter<Object, Object>>(2);

        private TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter;

        public DateItemListener(TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter) {
            this.sorter = sorter;
        }

        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
            filters.clear();
            String selected = event.getItem().toString();
            if (!selected.equals("ALL")) {
                filters.add(RowFilter.dateFilter(
                        ComparisonType.AFTER, calculateAfterDate(
                                selected)));
                filters.add(RowFilter.dateFilter(
                        ComparisonType.BEFORE, new Date()));
            }
            RowFilter<Object, Object> serviceFilter =
                    RowFilter.andFilter(filters);
            sorter.setRowFilter(serviceFilter);
        }

        // Returns the date as wanted.
        private Date calculateAfterDate(String selected) {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

            if (selected.equals("LAST 1 WEEK")) {
                cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -7);
                // Make 1 less date so I can get the EQUALS day.
                // Because of ComparisonType.AFTER
                cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
            } else if (selected.equals("LAST 1 MONTH")) {
                cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
                cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
            } else if (selected.equals("LAST 1 YEAR")) {
                cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1);
                cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
            }

            return cal.getTime();
        }

    }

    public class LocalDateItemListener implements ItemListener {

        private TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter;

        public LocalDateItemListener(TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter) {
            this.sorter = sorter;
        }

        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
            String selected = event.getItem().toString();
            LocalDate afterDate = calculateAfterDate(selected);

            sorter.setRowFilter(null);

            RowFilter<TableModel, Integer> localDateFilter =
                    new RowFilter<TableModel, Integer>() {
                @Override
                public boolean include(Entry<? extends TableModel,
                        ? extends Integer> entry) {
                    TableModel model = entry.getModel();
                    LocalDate date = (LocalDate) model.getValueAt(
                            entry.getIdentifier(), 1);
                    return date.isAfter(afterDate) &&
                            date.isBefore(LocalDate.now());
                }
            };

            if (!selected.equals("ALL")) {
                sorter.setRowFilter(localDateFilter);
            }
        }

        private LocalDate calculateAfterDate(String selected) {
            LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();

            if (selected.equals("LAST 1 WEEK")) {
                date = date.plusDays(-7);
                date = date.plusDays(-1);
            } else if (selected.equals("LAST 1 MONTH")) {
                date = date.plusMonths(-1);
                date = date.plusDays(-1);
            } else if (selected.equals("LAST 1 YEAR")) {
                date = date.plusYears(-1);
                date = date.plusDays(-1);
            }

            return date;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: This is not just answer. This is such a lesson. Thanks for your work sir and i am realy grateful for that.